# R: How to do calculation for the most recent 2 years

Tags: r

My data frame is in R with 4 columns: **ID, Date, X, Y**. Each ID will have many X & Y values with dates can range from 100 years down to 1 year. Granularity is monthly.

I would like to do a cumulative sum of X*Y for each ID, but with only the most recent 2 years only. Thanks for your help guys.

**REVISED**

Hi, For example I have the following data

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame = tibble(ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                    Year=c(2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015),
                    X=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                    Y=c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20))
print(data.frame)
```

I would want my result to be

```
result = tibble(ID=c(1,2), sum = c(26,46))
result
```

The calculation for ID=1 would be 1+2+11+12, and ID=2 would be 6+7+16+17. I only want the sum of the most recent 2 years. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I really understand how your dataset looks like and what you want, but you might be able to extend my approach from here:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(chron)

set.seed(0)

# test dataset
tibble(ID=1:10,Date=Sys.Date()-c(0:9*365),X=sample(1:10),Y=sample(1:10)) %>%

  # ID     Date           X     Y
  # <int> <date>         <int> <int>
  # 1     1 2019-09-24     6     4
  # 2     2 2018-09-24     1     1
  # 3     3 2017-09-24     4     9
  # 4     4 2016-09-24     7     5
  # 5     5 2015-09-25     5     7
  # 6     6 2014-09-25     9     8
  # 7     7 2013-09-25     3     6
  # 8     8 2012-09-25     8     2
  # 9     9 2011-09-26    10     3
  # 10    10 2010-09-26    2    10

  # extract years
  mutate(Year=as.numeric(as.character(years(Date)))) %>%

  # most recent two years
  filter(Year %in% (as.numeric(as.character(years(Sys.Date())))-0:1)) %>%

  # your cumulative sum
  mutate(cum_var=cumsum(X*Y))

#      ID Date           X     Y  Year cum_var
#   <int> <date>     <int> <int> <dbl>   <int>
# 1     1 2019-09-24     5     6  2019      30
# 2     2 2018-09-24     9     4  2018      66
```

EDIT: Based on your edit here's another example.

```
df <- df %>%
  # reduce cols
  mutate(sum=X*Y) %>%
  select(-X,-Y) %>%

  # split per ID
  split(.,.$ID)

# identify two most recent years for each ID
lapply(df, function(x){
  x %>% mutate(recent=ifelse(Year %in% c(max(Year,na.rm=T)-c(0,1)),T,F))
}) %>%

  # bind to whole dataset again
  bind_rows() %>%

  # remove other years
  filter(recent) %>%
  select(-recent,-Year) %>%

  # summarise
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_all(sum,na.rm=T)

#     ID   sum
#    <dbl> <dbl>
#  1   1    26
#  2   2    46
```

However, I have no clue about what you mean with cumsum of `X*Y`. Thus, I first did X*Y and used a normal `sum()` afterwards. You'll have to adjust this part.

Comment: Hi, I revised my question with examples now. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't assign data.frame as a variable name considering that it is already a declared function data.frame(). I will use df henceforth.

Here is a data.table solution. It evaluates the sums of X and Y across the two largest years recorded for each ID. Hence, it would also work if for ID == 2 the largest years were 2003 and 2004, for instance.

```
df = data.table(df)
mat = df[, .(
            Value = sum(X[Year %in% sort(Year, T)[1:2]]) + sum(Y[Year %in% sort(Year, T)[1:2]])
            ), keyby = ID]
> mat
   ID Value
1:  1    26
2:  2    46
```

Edit: You say X*Y although your sample for the output indicates X+Y for each of the two most recent years. My code evaluates X+Y and gives your indicated values (26, 46).